# Facing issue with nine patch images in android

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am beginner to Android SDK. I have explored few things to support multiple screens on Android.

I came up with nine patch images can serve this purpose.

Say i have image in which there are no part which i can repeat horizontally and vertically. 
Will nine patch image always solve problem with all type of images to support multiple screen sizes?? What would be best possible solution for such type of image??

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create the 9 patch so it stretches empty/background space if needed and not distort/stretch/repeat your image.

Using the [draw 9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) tool you would fill all border areas unlike choosing points.

Comment: Say if i have image in which there are no parts from where i can resize the image then how can we create nine patch image??